# Add dynamically methods to a class : using macro function into header file

Tags: c++, macros

Trying to avoid write a repeating code; I used macros to delare methods into a class. 
I want to define a macro function into header file like :

**cracker.h**

```
#include<message.h>
class Cracker {
    #define DECLARE_MSG(MSG_NAME, MSG_TYPE,ALREADY_DEFINED)      \
    { \                                                                                

        if(!ALREADY_DEFINED)                                                           
        {                                                                                \
            virtual bool cbProcessMsg_##MSG_NAME (API::MSG_NAME##Msg const & msg);                         \
        }\
    #include "message.h"
    #undef DECLARE_MSG
    };
```

**message.h**

```
DECLARE_MSG(AddOrder , 'A', false);
DECLARE_MSG(DeleteOrder , 'B', true);
DECLARE_MSG(ReplaceOrder , 'C', false);
...
```

But this code does note compile because I have not the right to add if statement outside a function.

Is there any alternative to do that ?

Comment: Before executing the maco, cant you just make something like `if(!ALREADY_DEFINED) EEDOS_DECLARE_OMXNORDIC_MSG_TYPE (AddOrder , 'A')` so you will avoid this ALREADY_DEFINED situation ?

Comment: is there meant to be a \ after `if(!ALREADY_DEFINED)` ? also it looks like you are using a symbol before it is defined

Comment: @Xatyrian : no, I can't do that because  ALREADY_DEFINED is passed as the third parameter of the macro.

Comment: @Caleth : I use \ as a line continuation escape character : to extend the macro into multiple lines

Comment: @MohamedAliChebbi Why do you need `ALREADY_DEFINED` ? When do you have to set it to true ? I think you have to share a little more details on your code

Comment: @Xatyrian : in message.h : i declared several DECLARE_MSG macro for every message 

DECLARE_MSG (AddOrder                     , 'A', false);
DECLARE_MSG (AddOrderMPIDAttribution      , 'F', true);...

Comment: And what is it used for, if ``ALREADY_DEFINED`` is ``true``? Then nothing should happen? If so, why do you need it?

Comment: @ Sebastian Stern: I'm calling DECLARE_MSG  in other part of the code like :     #define DECLARE_MSG(MSG_NAME, MSG_TYPE, ALREADY_DEFINED)       \
  {                                                                                    \
   if(ALREADY_DEFINED)                                                             \
   {                                                                                \
    const char msg_id[4] = { 'T' , '_' , MSG_TYPE , 0 };                         \

Comment: Please do not do this. I've worked with code that did things like this and they are a nightmare to debug and understand.

Comment: @crashmstr : I wish not use this technique and use templates and inheritence instead; but It's an existing code in production , and Itn't in my scope to change that.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of items worth highlighting:

1.
Macros do not know scope;  the only way you can remove it's definition is to undefine it.

2.
macros are pasted into the code as is; and then compiled.  A macro isn't a function itself, it's a code generation tool.  This means that even if 'ALREADY_DEFINED' is true, you'll get another definition.

3.
What you're trying to do is add a function into the class outside of the class definition. You just can't do this.  Ever.

4.
Header guards will save you pain for medium to large projects; you should get into the habbit of using them early.

While not quite the same, what it looks like you want to do is look up what the factory pattern is.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BOOST_PP_IIF` if you (can) use the boost-library:

```
#define DECLARE_MSG(MSG_NAME, MSG_TYPE,ALREADY_DEFINED)    \                                                                                
    BOOST_PP_IIF(ALREADY_DEFINED,, \                                                                                                                     
        virtual bool cbProcessMsg_##MSG_NAME (API::MSG_NAME##Msg const & msg);                         \
    )
```

You should use `0` and `1` instead of `false` and `true` here.

But if you don't, you can 'branch' definitions by concating name and number to another macro:

```
// two definitions for PP_CONCAT to expand macros, etc...
#define PP__CONCAT(a, b) a ## b
#define PP_CONCAT(a, b) PP__CONCAT(a, b)

// to expand your macro you should pass it through another macro
#define PP_EXPAND(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define DECLARE_MESSAGE_0(MSG_NAME, MSG_TYPE) /** the def when ALREADY_DEFINED = 0 */
#define DECLARE_MESSAGE_1(MSG_NAME, MSG_TYPE) /** the other branch */

#define DECLARE_MESSAGE(MSG_NAME, MSG_TYPE, ALREADY_DEFINED) \
    PP_EXPAND(PP_CONCAT(DECLARE_MESSAGE_, ALREADY_DEFINED)(MSG_NAME, MSG_TYPE))
```

When you have problems understanding the preprocessor, you should check out the output with the option -E / running the code with the command `cpp`(which stands for **c**-**p**re**p**rogressor and *not* **c****p**lus**p**lus(->`c++`))

However there may be another way to do the same thing, with templates and inheritance...